Why modern calling conventions pass variadic arguments in registers?
If we look at a few modern calling conventions, like x86-64 SysV style or AArch64 style (document aapcs64.pdf titled "Procedure Call Standard for the Arm® 64-bit Architecture"), we see explicit notes that variadic arguments are passed in the same way as other arguments. For example, a function call open(path, mode, cflags) on x86-64 will get path in RDI, mode in RSI and (the only variadic one) cflags in RDX.
There is no question with passing static argument set in registers, it is good for resource saving. But if we look into a function that then interprets arguments and so calls va_start for them, we will see that va_start is converted into putting all possible arguments (typically, much more than present really) onto stack; for example, full emulation of printf via vfprintf starts with (I compacted similar rows to avoid too long listings):
my_printf:
        endbr64
; nearly unconditional saving
        subq    $216, %rsp
        movq    %rsi, 40(%rsp)
<...>
        movq    %r9, 72(%rsp)
        testb   %al, %al
        je      .L2
        movaps  %xmm0, 80(%rsp)
<...>
        movaps  %xmm7, 192(%rsp)
; repacking into registers for enclosed vfprintf
.L2:
        movq    %fs:40, %rax
        movq    %rax, 24(%rsp)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    $8, (%rsp)
        movl    $48, 4(%rsp)
        leaq    224(%rsp), %rax
        movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
        leaq    32(%rsp), %rax
        movq    %rax, 16(%rsp)
        movq    %rsp, %rcx
        movq    %rdi, %rdx
        movl    $1, %esi
; finally, call the function
        movq    stdout(%rip), %rdi
        call    __vfprintf_chk@PLT
... skipped epilogue

Here 192 bytes of VA frame. Similarly, AArch64 version pushes 184 bytes (x1..x7 and q0..q7).
If the variadic tail of any function call had been always put on stack, things would have got much simpler in code and cheaper in runtime, because all packing and copying had not been needed. va_start would have been reduced to a single move of variadic list starting location (in stack) to a variable. This is how it really worked with i386 (where all arguments were passed on stack). Assembly output of the same trivial wrapper for Linux/i386:
my_printf:
        pushl   %ebx
        subl    $8, %esp
        call    __x86.get_pc_thunk.bx
        addl    $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, %ebx
        leal    20(%esp), %eax ; <--- This is va_start
        pushl   %eax ; VA pointer pushed for vfprintf
        pushl   20(%esp)
        pushl   $1
        movl    stdout@GOT(%ebx), %eax
        pushl   (%eax)
        call    __vfprintf_chk@PLT

Here, the question: why variadic arguments implementation, at least for x86-64 and aarch64, is that complicated and resource wasting?
(I could imagine that there were cases when two styles, both with fixed arguments and with a variadic list, should have been equally allowed in function declarations of the same function. But I donʼt know a case for it. The mentioned open is unlikely the one.)

"Modern" and "variadic argument lists" are mutually exclusive. Basically ABIs are just forced to deal with it somehow because they must still support old 1970s Unix crap like stdio.h. But nobody would call 1970s functions like printf and open and expect amazing performance in return. Those who do rather kind of deserve what's coming at them...

The way open works is a large part of this -- while it is declared as a varargs function, in the library it is generally implemented as a non-varargs function with 3 arguments.  The third argument is just not used in some cases.  This is because historically, declarations did not contain info about arguments at all.  When the interface was extended to support ANSI C (89), varargs was used to make the existing uses work.

Please note that solutions go in answers, not in edits to the question.

Note that not all calling conventions do so.  For example, the AArch64 calling convention used on macOS passes variadic arguments on the stack.
That said, a key motivation for passing variadic arguments in registers is that this makes it so neither caller nor callee need to know if a function is variadic or not.  For example, if you were to call a prototype-less function declared such:
int printf();

you wouldn't be able to know if it's a variadic function or not.  But by virtue of variadic and non-variadic functions having the same calling convention, the caller can simply set AL as if it was a variadic function and call it, with the callee ignoring AL if it is not.
This is not possible with the macOS calling convention, where executing programs that don't consistently declare variadic functions with prototypes will fail.

Hmm, prototype-less functions in C is the thing I fully missed out of sight. It looks like this is the reason :(
Why they were not banned out in modern ABIs or converted to stack-only mode, this is another question... Iʼd rather do this.

@Netch That's what macOS does.  However, legacy code may have K&R declarations mixed and matched with prototyped definitions (and vice versa), which was a much bigger concern back when most calling conventions were laid out, than it is today.

@Netch: x86-64 SysV was designed in Nov 2000 by Jan Hubicka.  C99 was still new, many years before macOS's variant of AArch64.  By that time everyone knew that unprototyped functions were a bad idea, but legacy code-bases using them were still a realistic concern.  Especially for something you're going to bake into the ABI, such that -std=c89 can't fix it.  (I haven't tried to search the x86-64.org mailing list on archive.org to look for discussion of variadic functions.)

Notably int printf(); will soon (C23) result in a function declaration expecting no parameters (void). So then the ABI will be forced to decide at what extent they'll want to drag old crap along. This was already flagged as obsolescent in year 1989 (C89 6.9.4). There's been a 35 year transit period to convert programs. Unfortunately they'll have to support variadic functions still, since stdarg.h has not yet been flagged as obsolecent. As usual, stdio.h is ultimately to blame.

@Lundin One of the greatest features of C is that legacy code often compiles without any changes; this includes code predating the ANSI C standard. I hope this will never change.

Note well that regardless of ABI, C language semantics (all versions) are that a function declared without a prototype is non-variadic.  The number and types of its parameters are not specified by such a declaration, but they are nevertheless fixed.  Even on a platform that uses different calling conventions for variadic and non-variadic functions, no version of C is ambiguous about which convention to use for any given function call.

@Lundin It is uselessly radical to declare variadic functions as legacy. All developed languages have them. The concrete style, well, may be reconsidered.

@fuz We already see that "compilation" means nothing if old code was written using implied guarantees that are not working anymore, like e.g. sizeof(int)==sizeof(void*) or absence of strong aliasing. I'd prefer Rust style with explicit marking the target feature set and language version. Anyway this is for another discussion.

@fuz It changed in the year 1999...

@Netch You have to realize the historical reasons why all old languages have it. Back in the pioneer era of the 1960s-1970s, nobody had a clue about what would be considered good or bad program design let alone what might be dangerous practices. Instead languages competed over who would have the most features? "Ah so you have goto? Hah! We have goto on steroids - setjmp!" "Oh but we have variadic functions!" "We support one's complement!" And so on. As a result, languages ended up with a complete clusterf* of dangerous and pointless features.

@Lundin Java, C#, Python are not 1970s. Rust is yet more newer but supports variadics in macros. And so on. I understand what you mean but canʼt agree. This is a basic feature and a languageʼs task is merely how to implement it in the most pertinent and safe way.

@Netch They don't have to. Because it is very hard if not impossible to find a use-case where the requirements of the implementation forces you to use variadic functions because that's the only sensible design alternative. Also a lot of those languages support function overloading, making variadic functions even more irrelevant. As does inheritance.

@Netch It's the same thing as with cars - cars can go up to some 200km/h but just because the car can do that doesn't mean that you should frequently travel at 200km/h. It's plain dangerous and besides illegal in most of the world. Just because a language provides a feature, that doesn't mean that we must use that feature nor that there's a sensible rationale behind said feature. In case of C, the majority of all language features do not come with a sensible rationale behind them, but often with a tons of historical backwards-compatibility burdens that have to be dragged around.

It would be perfectly possible for the implementation to automatically transform varargs functions to fixed argument list functions, simply by having the ... replaced by a pointer to the rest of the parameter list — if prototype-less function calls are banned.  It's the backwards-compatibility with old-style int printf(); that's the trouble here.
